# VBA return struct Type from Function

Tags: vba, excel, struct

i use EXCEL VBA:
i do a SQL query (SELECT * FROM CARS)

here is my SQL Function:

```
Public Type SqlReturnMyCar
 Name As String
 Color As String
 Vmax As Integer
 Price As Double
End Type

Public Function SqlQueryTest(Query As String) As SqlReturnMyCar

 'open connection
   cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DbSource

 'set recordSet
   Set rs = cn.Execute(Query)
   i = 0
'recordset to Excel sheet
   Do While Not rs.EOF


    Dim myCar As SqlReturnMyCar
    myCar(i).Name = rs.Fields("NAME")
    myCar(i).Color = rs.Fields("COLOR")
    myCar(i).Vmax = rs.Fields("VMAX")
    myCar(i).Price = rs.Fields("PRICE")

     i = i + 1
     rs.MoveNext
       Loop

    'close connection
       cn.Close

    'return values
        Set SqlQueryTest = myCar
        Set myCar = Nothing

    End Function
```

The query works in another function without typestructure.
i get the error: **Object required**.
*Where is the Problem and how looks a SQL Function in the right way?*
Maybe i got another Table Trucks with the following struct:

```
Public Type SqlReturnMyTruck
 Name As String
 Color As String
 Vmax As Integer
 Price As Double
 Size as Double
 Weight as Double
End Type
```

if i send the Query( SELECT * FROM TRUCKS )
now the table got 2 more colums ?
do i need another SQL Function?

Thanks for your help

Comment: where is "MyCar" being defined? It seems this could be the object it is looking for.

Comment: only in the Function: Dim myCar As SqlReturnMyCar

Comment: MyCar is not a collection, its one instance of your type.

Comment: sorry, not sure how i missed it. you are treating "mycar" as an istance of an object, while also treating it as a collection, you may need a new variable for a collection / list, and a second as an object / instance

Comment: Thanks, I updated this

Comment: your code still wont work doing it like that.  Your code is populating, trying to a collection, but returning a single.

Comment: Hmm okay i think the problem is the Set part at the end maybe I need brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this

`dim myCar() as SqlReturnMyCar
redim myCar(rs.Recordcount)`

instead of

`dim myCar as SqlReturnMyCar`

Comment: Okay thanks! how should i call the function form my form? **dim myCar() as SqlReturnMyCar** Set myCar = SqlQueryTest("(SELECT * FROM CARS") ?

Comment: You will need to create it the same, so something like `cars() as SqlReturnMyCar:cars=SqlQueryTest("(SELECT * FROM CARS") `

Comment: As your function return is of collection type, you can just say `dim cars as new collection:cars=SqlQueryTest("(SELECT * FROM CARS")` and then just `set myCar=new collection` in the function

Comment: ** Public function SqlQueryTest(Query As String) as Collection** ? Or as SqlReturnMyCar? Can I access the values like cars(0).name?

Comment: I want to return a struct if myCar so i need the SqlReturnMyCar as returnType

Comment: You cant try to populate a collection then.

Comment: Ok I think I must set the returnType to SqlReturnMyCar? But how can I access them from the form?